# get 3 first json object from huge json file with gson

Tags: java, json, gson

I have a large file with a lot of json inside
for example:

```
{
   "id":1,
   "text":"foo the bar",
   ...
},
{
   "id":2,
   "text":"foo the bar",
   ...
},
{
   "id":3,
   "text":"foo the bar",
   ...
},
{
   "id":4,
   "text":"foo the bar",
   ...
},...
```

I want to take the only 3 first objects, I tried this code, but I get an exception "not a valid json format".

```
JsonReader reader = new JsonReader( new FileReader(path) );
reader.beginArray();
int i = 0;
while (reader.hasNext() && i < 3) {
    JsonParser  _parser = new JsonParser();
    JsonElement jsonElement =  _parser.parse(reader);
    JsonObject jsonObject = jsonElement.getAsJsonObject();
    //Do something
}
```

of course I tried to change me reader.beginArray() with beginsObject().
I dont want to open all the file also..
Any help?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Like the message said it is not a valid json format. It should look like this

```
[{
   "id":1,
   "text":"foo the bar",
   ...
},
{
   "id":2,
   "text":"foo the bar",
   ...
},
{
   "id":3,
   "text":"foo the bar",
   ...
},
{
   "id":4,
   "text":"foo the bar",
   ...
},...]
```

The json objects must be inside an array.